# I need to find a specific maximum principle

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations

I need a maximum principle that says:

> If $L$ is an elliptic operator and $u$ is a positive function ($u\in C^2(\Omega)$, with $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ an unbounded domain) such that
>   $Lu\geq0$ in $\Omega$ and $\limsup_{|x| \to \infty} u\leq0$,
>   then
>   $u\leq0$ in $\Omega$.

If you know a maximum principle like that, please tell me the book or text.

Thank you!

Comment: Questions are supposed to be answered here, not by email.

Comment: Im sorry Michael. Im new here, if anyone knows about this theme, please answer here so.

Comment: Please delete the copy of your question, one version is enough.

Comment: I cleaned up your question a bit and removed your email address.  Please check that it is still accurate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the usual maximum principle, $u$ attains its maximum on $B(0,n)$ at some $x_n \in \partial B(0,n)$.  Then $u(x_n)$ is an increasing sequence and hence converges to some $M$.  Since $|x_n| \to \infty$, we have $M \le 0$.  But on the other hand, by definition of $M$ we have $u \le M$ everywhere.